# Соотношение сторон Unity

Tags: unity3d

Здравствуйте,подскажите,делаю 2D игру,реализована она: кнопки и весь UI на Canvas-e,игровые объекты находятся вне canvas,на данный момент использую orthographic камеру,столкнулся с проблемой соотношения сторон.Делал игру под 16:9 в ней нормально,но если взять к примеру 4:3 оно сжимается в центр. Смена ortographic.size учитывая aspect приводит к тому,что видно много лишнего вне canvas(игровые объекты просто расставлены перед canvas и находятся чуть ближе к камере).Как можно реализовать нормальное масштабирование?(если не менять size,то просто игра сжимается по горизонтали к центру).FoV-возможное решение но это перспективная камера(или всё-таки даже для 2D игры использовать перспективную камеру?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот скрипт который я использую у себя:

```
public class CameraScalerComponent : MonoBehaviour
    {

        [SerializeField] private Camera _camera;

        private const float DefaultAspectRatio = 1.775f; // iPhone 5 landscape ratio
        private const float DefaultOrthographicSize = 10f;

        private void Awake()
        {
            _camera.orthographicSize = DefaultOrthographicSize;

            _camera.projectionMatrix = Matrix4x4.Ortho(
            -DefaultOrthographicSize * DefaultAspectRatio, 
            DefaultOrthographicSize * DefaultAspectRatio,
            -DefaultOrthographicSize, DefaultOrthographicSize,
            _camera.nearClipPlane, _camera.farClipPlane);
        }
    }
```

За основу берется соотношение пятого айфона, остальные подгоняются под эти пропорции.

Comment: Спасибо,теперь осталось сделать,чтоб canvas не уменьшался и будет отлично,спасибо)